# Is there a way to get search keywords from search engines?

Tags: php

I am using this code:

```
echo $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER].'<br>';
echo $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING].'<br>';
```

but it only show me the domain name and not the keywords.

Comment: Can you please explain further what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Very Very Very smple task. First look at the complete referrer to see if at all keyword was sent and if so then in which field? then simply parse that to grab it. If the referrer doesn't have that value, you don't have it. Simple

Comment: the problem is that with https, google doesn't show me keywords but only the domain "www.google.com"

Comment: referer can never be relied on ever, http is a stateless protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and now. More and more Google (and other search engine) users are using HTTPS, which means that referrer data is not sent to 3rd party sites. From the plain old HTTP referer headers should contain the search terms.

See http://www.notprovidedcount.com/

Comment: So is there no way to get these keywords from https pages ?

Comment: Nope, there is no way.

Comment: even in javascript or other languages ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, HTTPS allows sharing referer header only with other HTTPS sites.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer "If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the referer field is not sent.[9]" but Google and other search engines could just use rel="noreferer" and then there is absolutely no way to get that info.